# How to display the data and stepper in one cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

when I use this code, but the details are stepper does not work (can be seen in the logs)

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"CellIDD";
Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
Data *item = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.accessoryView = [self newStepper];
    if (NSStringFromClass([UIStepper class]))
        [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setTag:indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row];
    else
        [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setTag:indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row];
}
if (NSStringFromClass([UIStepper class]))
{
    [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMinimumValue:0];
    [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMaximumValue:18];
    [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setValue:[[_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
}
else
{
    [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMinimumValue:0];
    [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMaximumValue:18];
    [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setValue:[[_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
}
cell.cellTextLabel3.text = item.name;
cell.cellPriceLabel3.text = item.bounty;
cell.labelSnipper.text = [[_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
    NSLog(@"VALUE  %@",_values);
    return cell;}
```

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s17/sh/49a47862-95e0-4266-90cd-0fc1b523107b/e208bba10a1cc1618dbdf4aef13264fe/deep/0/CellIDD.png

and if you use this code, it is not clear labels for by logs shows that the stepper works

```
NSString *cellID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CellID%d", indexPath.row]; 
Cell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
 Data *item = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[Cell3 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.accessoryView = [self newStepper];
        if (NSStringFromClass([UIStepper class]))
            [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setTag:indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row];
        else
            [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setTag:indexPath.section * 100 + indexPath.row];
    }
    if (NSStringFromClass([UIStepper class]))
    {
        [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMinimumValue:0];
        [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMaximumValue:18];
        [(UIStepper *)cell.accessoryView setValue:[[_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
    }
    else
    {
        [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMinimumValue:0];
        [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setMaximumValue:18];
        [(CustomStepper *)cell.accessoryView setValue:[[_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue]];
    }
    cell.cellTextLabel3.text = item.name;
    cell.cellPriceLabel3.text = item.bounty;
    cell.labelSnipper.text = [[_values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];
        NSLog(@"VALUE  %@",_values);
        return cell;
     }
```

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s17/sh/1601451a-af62-4c35-9d27-4f23252ad50a/4ea3c85e0c38372b105e72cbaa58d942/deep/0/CellID%20d.png

Comment: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s17/sh/e687aebb-0d4c-42f1-95c9-ecb01bbf2ca4/9b7983cc4077f335d6659104fdeaea21/deep/0/%D0%A1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%2007.08.13,%2010:48.png

Comment: "stepper next to the data how much was trying to do" -- this is unintelligible.

Comment: Probyval different versions of the code. at the moment I have two versions of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to setup the cell in the storyboard. Change the size of the dynamic prototype cell to what you want, and drag in a label and a stepper. The type of the cell should be set to custom, and you should create a subclass of UITableViewCell. Change the class of the cell to your subclass, and setup IBOutlets in the cell class's .h file for any UI elements that you dragged in. Connect up those outlets in the usual way, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, there is a problem, that the cells are displaying no content at all?

Remove the "D" from "CellIDD" and "%d" from "CellID%d". In most cases you will design a single  prototype cell within the storyboard and specify an identifier ("CellID" in your case). The dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method will get you one cell of the type "CellID" and use it for filling the table with cells.

Besides...

```
if (NSStringFromClass([UIStepper class]))
```

... will always resolve to YES. I guess something is missing there and you wanted to check, wether the accessory view of the cell is of type UIStepper.

Comment: the problem is that I do not understand how to display and record labels and stepper at a given time.